# React-router: Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactRoute is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I'm following [React Router Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md) but I'm not even getting to make the simplest example to work. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: Route is not defined`.

I'm including these 3 JavaScript files through `cdnjs` and my own script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/0.11.6/react-router.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx" src="react/routing/routes.jsx"></script>
```

And the script the triggers the exception is `routes.jsx`:

```
var routes = (
   <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
       <DefaultRoute handler={MainPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

Am I missing anything? Have `Route` been renamed?

Comment: You have a closing </Route> tag but not an opening one?

Comment: Thanks @Chris . That was a type. The code is correct. Still I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `ReactRouter.Route`.

You can open the console and see the various properties of objects.

Also, take a look at [the exports](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/index.js).  In the browser exports becomes ReactRouter, in commonjs it's the return value of `require('react-router')`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm not familiar with `require`. I guess the `cdnjs` does't make these exports.. because `Route` is not available. Thank you.

Comment: The exports are there, but in the browser global build the exports from that file end up as the ReactRouter global variable.